# How can i add a max to a checkbox form with bootstrap 4 button-groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4, buttongroup

I have this form with questions that uses checkboxes and radiobuttons, the checkbox questions can have a max amount of checked needed to go to the next question. For the checkboxes and radio buttons i am using the bootstrap buttons.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

I use jquery change function to see when something happens to the checkbox, when something changes i check how many are checked and compare it with the max amount. If the amount of checked is higher than the max then i uncheck the checkbox that was just checked. Problem with this is that when a checkbox unchecks it changes the checkbox and I get an infinite loop and end up getting the error "too much recursion".

Any clue on how I can make this work? I've tried .click instead of .change but then when I get the amount of checked it gives me the wrong number.

Script:

```
function checkboxHandler(aThis){
    if($('.pro-block.pb-active').find('.proanalysecheck:checked').length > $(aThis).data('max')) {
        if($(aThis).prop('checked') == true){
            $(aThis).parent('label').button('toggle');
        }
    }
}


$('#frmProinvite .proanalysecheck').change( function(e) {
    checkboxHandler(this);
});
```

`.pb-block.pb-active` is the current question div and `.proanalysecheck` is the input class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a flag which indicates that a change is caused by reaching the max selections? This should do the job.

```
var changeByMaxReached = false; 
function checkboxHandler(aThis){
    if(!changeByMaxReached && $('.pro-block.pb-active').find('.proanalysecheck:checked').length > $(aThis).data('max')) {
        if($(aThis).prop('checked') == true){
            changeByMaxReached = true;
            $(aThis).parent('label').button('toggle');
        }
    }
}


$('#frmProinvite .proanalysecheck').change( function(e) {
    if (!changeByMaxReached) {
        checkboxHandler(this);
    } 
    changeByMaxReached = false;
});
```